# Padding problems with sidebar/content/footer

Tags: html, css

I'm having padding problems. My sidebar is 318px wide, my content is 642px wide, and my footer is 642px wide and lines up with my content. My sidebar and content **both** have a padding of 20px all around, but my sidebar is supposed to go full height to the bottom of the page and extend whenever there is more content which also pushes down the footer. I'm sorry if this is too much information but I'm trying to give as much detail as possible.

[Here is a link to what I have so far](http://redsky.incredifull.com/)
You can also view source if needed for the complete HTML. I only figured the elements I'm talking about are needed but that's for just in case there's more to it.

HTML:

```
<!-- SIDEBAR -->
<div id="sidebar">
 <h1>Caul / Cbua</h1>


<div class="sidetext">
Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam laoreet mi c est dignissim,     at auctor mi tristique.
</div>

<h1>Commit</h1>
<div class="sidelink">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div id="content">
<h1>News</h1>

<div class="article">
<img class="articleimg" src="../../Slicing Images/news images/caul.png" width="84" height="65" alt="caul" />

<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<h3>Friday, August 16th</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div id="footer">
&copy; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background-color: #e7d9c9;
    background-image: url('/imgs/map.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
/* height 100? */
width: 318px;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidetext {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    width:300px;
}

.sidelink ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.sidelink li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidelink li a {
    display:block;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#1e416f;
    padding:5px;
    border-left:10px solid #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink li a:hover {
    border-left:14px solid #1e416f;
    background-color:#e7d9c9;
    color: #1e416f;
}

h5 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue: Light;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #517f9c;
}

/* Content */
#content {
width: 642px;
float: right;
}

.article {
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.articleimg {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 25px;
}


/* Footer */
#footer {
 font-family: Helvetica Neue: Regular;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #94b9c4; 
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In your example linked it looks as if the sidebar is on the top of the footer? if you go into inspector and delete the footer element the sidebar is extended to the bottom of the page. So I am just a little confused when you say "sidebar is supposed to go full height to the bottom of the page", do you mean you'd like the footer to be to the right of your sidebar?

Comment: Hi there Samuel. Thanks for the reply. Basically I'd like what you see in my example, just the proper way as I don't believe it's proper CSS to have "padding-bottom" everywhere. Isn't there a way to have 20px padding around everything in the sidebar and everything in the content like shown in my example?

Now I'm also unsure of where to place my footer because I'd like it towards the bottom more and inline with the content. So basically where it is now, just pushed down and sort of "stickied" and in line with the content.

Comment: Also, if I add more content, the sidebar doesn't go full height.

Comment: ok hold tight I'm gonna make some changes. I'll comment everything. I have taken the entire site down from the web, one moment.

Comment: For the footer, the reason the clear doesn't work is because it is inside the content div. Try taking it outside of the content div, make the width the same 642px and then float:right. I did that and I got the footer to be below the sidebar. I think that's what you are looking for?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ruD3u62.png?1

Comment: @barrigaj very very close! The ONLY problem with my footer now is that I'd like the beginning of the footer to be in line with the title "News". I tried adding a padding of 20px just like in the header, but no luck,

Comment: http://www.sfu.ca/~skobe/stackHelp/index.html you can have a look at this and let me know how close I am.

Comment: @samuelkobe Works perfect! All except for the sidebar being full height. It didn't show when I viewed your page either. I'm using Chrome so maybe that's it??

Comment: sorry that's just footer, moving to sidebar height now.

Comment: http://www.sfu.ca/~skobe/stackHelp/index.html Ok have a look i know its not exactly what you wanted I can continue to tweak if need be.

Comment: @samuelkobe Sorry Samuel! But I need it exactly like I stated :( Thanks so much for putting so much into it though!

Comment: http://www.sfu.ca/~skobe/stackHelp/index.html ok. How about this, that should do it.

Comment: @samuelkobe Is it possible without adding the extra links to make it go down farther? I only need the links that I had.

Comment: 100% height is tricky. I am not sure I can help you here.

Comment: http://www.sfu.ca/~skobe/stackHelp/index.html got it, here ya go

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>CAUL / CBUA</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="caul-logo">

        <h4>Nova Scotia Community College</h4>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div id="navi">
        <a href="#">Directories</a>
        <a href="#">Committees</a>
        <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </div>

    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="content">
        <h1>News</h1>

        <div class="article">
            <img class="articleimg" src="../../Slicing Images/news images/caul.png" width="84" height="65" alt="caul" />

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <h3>Friday, August 16th</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. 
                Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. 
                Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. 
                    Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. 
                    Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. 
                        Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. 
                        Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. 
                            Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. 
                            Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. 
                                Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. 
                                Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque a leo in lacus tempor egestas. 
                                    Maecenas faucibus neque nisi, eu condimentum enim porta id. Suspendisse blandit sem tellus. 
                                    Vivamus tristique, nunc faucibus pulvinar fringilla, sem ipsum molestie libero, id rhoncus turpis quam sit amet quam. </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- SIDEBAR -->
                            <div id="sidebar">
                                <h1>Caul / Cbua</h1>

                                <div class="sidetext">
                                    Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam laoreet mi c est dignissim, at auctor mi tristique.
                                </div>

                                <h1>Commit</h1>
                                <div class="sidelink">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- FOOTER -->
                            <div id="footer">
                                <p>&copy; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Main content styles */

html, body {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Regular;
}

h1 {
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Condensed Bold;
font-size: 24px;
color: #1d406f;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left: 20px;
}

h2 {
font-size: 18px;
color: #0f2233; 
}

h3, p {
font-size: 16px;
color: #0f2233;
}

a:link { color: #517f9c; }
a:highlight { color: #478ecc; text-decoration: underline; }

img {
display: block;
}

hr {
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Container */
#container {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height:100%;
}

/* Header */
#header {
width: 960px;
height: 282px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 0;
background-image: url('http://redsky.incredifull.com/imgs/header.jpg');
}

#caul-logo {
top: 35px;
left: 20px;
width: 298px;
height: 91px;
position: relative;
background-image: url('/imgs/caul-header-logo.png');
}

h4 {
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Condensed;
text-decoration: bold;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: relative;
top: 215px;
left: 675px;
}

/* Navigation bar */
#navi {
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Condensed Bold;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #1e416f;
height: 45px;   
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#navi a {
color: white;
margin-left: 20px;
}

#navi a:hover {
background: white;
color: #1e416f;
}

.login {
color: #517f9c;
}

/* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background-color: #e7d9c9;
background-image: url('/imgs/map.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 33.33333333333333%;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 20px;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;

}

#sidebar.h1 {
border-bottom: thick;
border-bottom-width: 75%;
}

.sidetext {
padding: 5px 20px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Helvetica Neue;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink {
padding-bottom: 20px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
width:300px;
}

.sidelink ul {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.sidelink li {
display: block;
list-style: none;
}

.sidelink li a {
display:block;
font-family: Helvetica Neue;
font-size:16px;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#1e416f;
padding:5px;
border-left:10px solid #FFF;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidelink li a:hover {
border-left:14px solid #1e416f;
background-color:#e7d9c9;
color: #1e416f;
}

h5 {
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Light;
font-size: 24px;
color: #517f9c;
}

/* Content */
#content {
width: 66.66666666666666%;
height: auto;
float: right;
padding-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
height:100%;
}

.article {
width: 99%;
padding: 5px 20px;
}

.articleimg {
float: left;
padding-right: 25px;
}


/* Footer */
#footer {
text-align: left;
bottom: 0;
font-family: Helvetica Neue: Regular;
font-size: 12px;
width: 66.666666666%;
float: right;
clear: both;
margin-top: -50px;
}

#footer p {
text-indent: 20px;
color: #94b9c4; 
}
```